Cant authenticate twitter API in Postman
Been following this blog - https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/tweet-to-super-followers-with-postman--oauth-2-0-and-manage-twee but cant successfully authenticate with twitter using postman with OAuth2.0. It gets stuck at getting new access token.
 .
I'm using a free tier, the app type set in twitter is confidential client. Saw this issue earlier in the POSTMAN discussion forum too but with no solution - https://community.postman.com/t/having-troblue-geting-access-token-oauth-2-0-request-timed-out-please-try-again/44473/1.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
I've followed docs and got it authenticated using CMD with CURL and was able to create a post. But with Postman stuck at getting access token.
